# Backed up MySql folder... upgraded to newer version and cant seem to recover data

Tags: mysql, macos

I copied the entire MySql folder "mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64" and installed a newer version "mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64".

I should have researched but thought the installer would handle moving the data over (I only backed up as a precaution).

After installing my older MySQL folder only has 'data' and 'keyring' and the new the obvious. My backed up folder seems to have everything the old MySQL did before the new install.

Is there a way to get the older data?

I've tried copying the data folder to the new install folder, data & keyring.

I'm on Mac. upgraded from MySQL 8.0.13 to 8.0.17

Comment: Ken, I tried that but doesn't seem to work on 8,0,17 perhaps?

Comment: Did you try searching on [dba.se] to see if the question was asked there?